# Is there a system for live kernel upgrade from 5.4 to 5.10?

Tags: kernel

I have tested ksplice uptrack on Ubuntu 20.04
I see It applies patches to live kernel.
For example:

```
Effective kernel version is 5.4.0-139.156
uptrack-upgrade -y
The following steps will be taken:
Install [w4h8q11e] CVE-2023-20938: Use-after-free in the Android Binder deriver.
Installing [w4h8q11e] CVE-2023-20938: Use-after-free in the Android Binder deriver.
Your kernel is fully up to date.
Effective kernel version is 5.4.0-144.161
```

The kernel is first 5.4.0-139
then became 5.4.0-144 without reboot.
My question is simple: did exist/works on Linux a "patch" or system to make the kernel "live upgrade" for example from 5.4.0-144 to 5.10.0-121?
I heard some years ago about an Intel patch about this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live kernel patching is meant to fix vulnerabilities, not upgrade kernel release. The fact that you're seeing that 5.4.0-139 became 5.4.0-144 is quite unusual. Perhaps Ubuntu does something to keep all the modules compatible within a single kernel release but that is *not* what upstream thinks is allowed or possible. Upstream insists you need to reboot even if you replaced e.g. 5.4.1 with 5.4.2.

Still upgrading to new major kernel releases via live patching is outright impossible.

- The kernel sees major changes between releases, including headers, thus often ABI/API.
- Any changes in the core kernel structures are reflected in kernel modules, thus they cannot be compatible with different kernel releases.

Live patching changes the kernel memory image. It cannot change modules on the disk.